# Error when using fs.writefile from container to write to mounted DFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am writing from a docker container to a dfs using `fs.writeFile`. 99% of the time the `writefile` works properly, but on occasion it returns an error. In the code, I create the file and don't access it again. Nothing else would be accessing the file either.

```
try {
     result = await this.writeFile(location, fileContent);
     this.logger.info('File got released successfully');
     } catch (error) {
     .....
     }
```

```
async writeFile(location, content) {
        const self = this;
        self.logger.info(`Creating the following file ${location}`);

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            fs.writeFile(location, content, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    self.logger.error(`Error creating file in the cloud at ${location}. Error: ${err}`);
                    const errMsg = `Error creating file in the cloud at ${location}. Error: ${err}`;
                    reject(errMsg);
                } else {
                    self.logger.info(`Successfully created ${location}`);
                    resolve(null);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

> Error: EIO: i/o error, open

Comment: Not sure what the question is here? The error tells you that the file is currently being held by another process.

Comment: This is the only process that is touching the file though. Write the file and then don't touch it. Is it possible it's prematurely trying to complete the writing before it's done?

Comment: if you're trying to write to the same file with the same process maybe in makes sense to use fs.writeFileSync instead of the async version